# From the Neo Koans => object.nil? or object == nil

Tags: ruby

I revisited the ruby koans and I saw something like

```
 # THINK ABOUT IT:¬                                                                              
 30     #¬                                                                                              
 31     # Is it better to use¬                                                                          
 32     #    obj.nil?¬                                                                                  
 33     # or¬                                                                                           
 34     #    obj == nil¬                                                                                
 35     # Why?
```

What really is better?

I am on the side of obj.nil since it is easier to read and shorter. But is there a solid proof on which is better?

Comment: I prefer `obj.nil?` to `obj=nil`. Oops! I meant `obj==nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj.nil?` is more readable and more efficient

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 500000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times do ; 1.nil?;   end }
  x.report { n.times do ; 1 == nil; end }
end

#     user     system      total        real
# 0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.056285)
# 0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.094164)
```

Comment: Huh? `obj.nil?` is one variable dereference (`obj`) and one message send (`nil?`). `obj == nil` is *two* variable dereferences (`obj` and `nil`) and one message send (`==`). How is that "more efficient" and how is that "avoiding one function call"?

Comment: My mistake ! I've corrected the answer

Comment: but isn't == a method? just syntactically sweet

Comment: `Object#nil?` is better as it represents unambiguous way to check if receiver is `nil`. The comparison operator method `==` does work as a side effect `NilClass` can't be instantiated. If it could and inherited `Object#==` was used, the result would be `false` because two different instances.

Comment: Btw. benchmarking here is about implementation detail and won't be surprised by different results between CRuby, JRuby or Opal.So it does not make much sense.

Comment: If you write `x.report "nil?" { n.times do ; 1.nil?; end }`, that row in the output will be labelled `nil?`.

Answer (score 1):

`obj.nil?` is also more amenable to modification. You could override it without fooling with the more general `==` method. A could could be using the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) where users also testing for nil directly with `nil?`.